# Memory seems to be leaking?

Tags: 10.10, memory, ram

My Memory is filling slowly. I have 2gb of ram, if i start the system 30% are used by apps. Now after some days it says 90% are used by apps. I know that linux is using as much as possible but its getting really slowly if the 90% are reached. And i dont know who is using it....my top command shows

```
  21   1 1260m 266m 9792 S    5 13.3   0:24.52 java                                                                         
  20   0 47160  308  276 S    0  0.0   1:05.65 udisks-daemon                                                                
  20   0  324m  16m 4808 S    0  0.8   1:10.92 gnome-terminal                                                               
  20   0  740m  15m 5996 S    0  0.8   7:41.15 soffice.bin                                                                  
  21   1  804m 191m  38m S    0  9.6   0:24.22 firefox-bin                                                                  
  20   0 19392 1392  956 R    0  0.1   0:00.02 top                                                                          
  20   0 23900  988  416 S    0  0.0   0:03.76 init
```

Any ideas? Memory leak?

Comment: Do you play minecraft, per chance?

Comment: What does `free` print? In `top` you can press `M` to sort processes by memory usage.

Comment: Its Eclipse, not Minecraft. And there is no process with more than 13.3 and 9.6 the other ones are <1.

Comment: well there's your problem...you're using java.  garbage collection is not happening for something imho.

Comment: Open `gnome-system-monitor`, and click on the memory tab so it shows the program using the most RAM, and add that to your question.

Comment: Is this memory really used by applications or does it include cache and buffers? The output of `free` could make this clear.

Comment: Its really used by applications! java does take the most ram.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments, you are using too many heavy applications at once. With so little RAM I suggest running fewer applications when using Eclipse and other heavy (especially interpreted) applications. Naturally most applications will slowly but surely increase the memory usage until you start to experience thrashing. To avoid this, restart the applications from time to time. If you are running Unity, you can also restart unity easily. Just run `unity` in the run dialogue to restart it. It will restart `compiz` as well, and free some memory.

Comment: Too many? Eclipse, Firefox and Thunderbird?!

Comment: @Markey: I'm pretty serious. Firefox (and Chrome) will use a lot of memory these days when you have multiple tabs, Thunderbird uses a lot of RAM, and Eclipse... come on. I've got 4GB and I struggle with RAM issues.
Software developers just don't bother to cut down on RAM hogging anymore.